# Tomcat ./version.sh searches for another(deleted) version

Tags: tomcat

I tried installing tomcat9 first and then switched to tomcat7. when executed ./version.sh command from /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.70/bin, it searches for tomcat9 in /home/admin as below;

```
[root@localhost bin]# pwd
/opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.70/bin
[root@localhost bin]# ./version.sh 
Cannot find /home/admin/apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M6-src/bin/setclasspath.sh
This file is needed to run this program
[root@localhost bin]#
```

Why does it happen ? What am I supposed to do to resolve it ?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved when I closed the terminal and reopened !